# rails 3 displaying a where

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

using the below code i can search a table using the question id and position  where position will be the biggest number

```
<%= @question = Question.where('question_group_id' =>params[:question_group_id]).order(params[:position]).last>
```

however i get

```
#<Question:0x3fe85c0>
```

how do i display it with the actual position number

thank you

I know it may be a repost but i found two or three answers on these boards pertaining to different questions  where the user got a similar result but they didnt help

Comment: try `@question.inspect`

Comment: end with `.last.try(:position)`

Comment: What exactly do you want to display from your `Question` instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this part in your controller:

```
@question = Question.where('question_group_id' => params[:question_group_id]).order(params[:position]).last
```

And you can use this part in your view to show all the attributes

```
<%= @question.inspect %>
```

Or to show one attribute you can use

```
<%= @question.position %>
```

Note that when you put it in the `<%= %>` tag it automatically will perform a `to_s`, so while you might see something more verbose printed in your console when you check what `@question` is, to get what will actually display, try `@question.to_s`

(also note that @question will not be available in the console, but you can copy and paste the relevant code)

Answer (score 1):

```
Question.
  where('question_group_id' => params[:question_group_id]).
  order(params[:position]).
  last
```

returns an instance of `Question`. That being said if you want the position you must get the attribute. So all you need is to call `.position` after `.last`